# How to implement server-to-client remote procedures?

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, client, client-server, grpc

## Problem

I need to implement this architecture:

- Clients can connect to a remote server to indicate they are online and operational
- The server can receive requests from various sources
- The server can issue orders to the clients
- For each order, the server needs to wait for an acknowledgement (or for an error) before sending the next order

The problem is that the server cannot *initiate* communications with the clients since they are behind a router and the ports are not forwarded.

[image]

## I thought about 2 possible solutions:

1) I use gRPC for everything:

- The clients call a `Connect` procedure on the server.
- This is a biderectional streaming RPC which is kept alive as long as the clients are online.
- The server uses this as a channel to send orders to the clients: the clients listen for messages on the stream, execute the order and return a message to specify whether the order succeeded or failed, along with some optional parameters

[image]

2) RabbitMQ/MQTT or some other pub/sub system

- Clients send heartbeats to the server to notify it that they are online and running
- The server uses RabbitMQ to issue orders to the clients
- To every issued order, the server expects the client to call an Acknowledgement RPC before sending the next order down RabbitMQ

[image]

## Question

Do you think these solutions are good enough for this particular problem? And if so, which one would you say is the best?

I'm particularly worried about:

- The first solution being too network intensive because of all the open connections
- The second solution doesn't provide a way for the server to know if the client crashed. In this situation the first solution would just drop the connection and the server could react appropriately.
- Both solutions provide a weak feedback system. The ideal thing to do for me would be to call a remote procedure from the server to the client but AFAIK this is not possible because of how RPC works. Also clients are behind NAT.

  I don't have much knowledge in this field of server-to-client requests and I don't know how these things are usually done. Can you help me out decide on a simple but powerful and scalable architecture for server-to-client procedure calls?